# Questions migrated to localized meta sites get the [discussion] tag in English even if it's synonymized to the localized tag equivalent

Tags: bug, tags, migration, per-site-meta, localization

Questions that get migrated to localized meta sites have the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag in English, instead of the localized equivalent of the tag.

E.g. in Russian Stack Overflow: in question [Где найти практику?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4980/1) base tag should be [[обсуждение]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/synonyms), not [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), which is a synonym in this case.

One more issue is that dupe hammer (gold badge for “обсуждение”) doesn’t close the question tagged “discussion”.

For context, the system adds the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag to questions that get migrated to meta sites, in order to ensure that all questions there have a required tag.

Comment: One positive artifact of this bug during Winter Bash 2021: due to [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374189/manual-key-hat-is-not-correctly-triggered-on-localized-sos), the Manual Key meta-only secret hat could not be earned on localized site metas, *except* those migrated to them.

Comment: Report of this issue on the Japanese version of StackOverflow (2015): [質問をメタに移行すると、討議タグではなくdiscussionタグが設定される](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1912/3054)

Comment: Kinda curious, considering the age of the issue, how common this is?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek we need to count every migration from localized sites to their metas. Maybe someone can write a SEDE query for this.