# Info page for synonym tag not redirected to its base tag page

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, redirection, russian-stackoverflow

Info page for synonym tag [[discussion]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info) on ruSO.meta doesn't redirected to its base tag info page [[обсуждение]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/info).

Related report: [Migrated to localized meta site questions have [discussion] tag in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292823/339911)

Comment: I'm guessing this is because [discussion] has been made a synonym of [обсуждение] on the SO in Russian site, but the two tags haven't been merged. According to the [Tag Synonyms page for that site](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), there are 2 questions that still have the [discussion] tag; per the related post you linked, I assume that's due to a question being migrated there from another site (and the tags not being edited afterwards to fix this issue)...