# On international sites, the Hot Meta Posts box incorrectly contains posts with moderator status tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, community-bulletin, international-sites

According to [What criteria is used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin (events / featured / hot meta posts / blog) sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/209901):

> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked with any moderator status tag, scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. (Note that the timing, score and tags [can be adjusted per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community)

This works well and no post with a status tag shows on, say, English Stack Overflow, Spanish Language, or others sites I visit regularly.

However, I noticed that on Stack Overflow en español, this is not the case. For example on February 27 I noticed (and [reported in Meta.SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3495/83)) in *Publicaciones populares en Meta* [a specific question](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3951/83) was showing:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

...despite the fact that it had been tagged with `[estado-completado]` [by February 25](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3951/revisions):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

This may have to do with the tag `[status-completed]` being a synonym of `[estado-completado]` and hitting a problem similar to the bug [Migrated to localized meta site questions have [discussion] tag in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292823/209901), so this case may be also happening on other international sites. Alternatively, it may simply be checking for a tag with `[status-*]` which is correct for the English sites but incorrect for the international sites.

Comment: Is this still an issue today? There was a change in which any status tag, not merely the completed tag, would prevent the post from being featured in Hot Meta Posts, so are other status tags affected?

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog yes, I keep seeing posts with [estado-completado] in the _Hot Meta Posts_ section for SOes. If I remember, I will ping you when I see another one.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog it happens again. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/on30y.png It reflects [this question](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4962/83) appearing in the HMP even though it has the tag ["estado-completado"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/estado-completado) (to which  [status-completed] is a synonym). The mod tag was added 12 hours ago, so I doubt it is still there because of caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed as [reported on es.meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5191/54018).

When generating the hot meta questions sidebar on non-English sites, we will now fetch the list of synonyms starting with `status-` and exclude posts with the target tag.

Comment: Would fixing the migration synonym bug linked in the last paragraph of the question be easy as well?