# 'Manual key' hat is not correctly triggered on localized SOs

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, international-sites, winter-bash-2021

The [trigger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list/373001#373001) for the "Manual key" hat have been discovered, but it doesn't work as expected on localized SOs (spoiler):

> The question must be tagged as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), but on localized SOs' Meta it's synonymized for a different name (there may be [exceptions](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8652)).

Manual key:

[image: Manual key hat]

Comment: Thanks for the report and catching this! We thought we'd written the code to catch synonyms but it doesn't seem to be recognizing them properly.  We still have some investigation to do here but we think we've figured out what's causing the issue and have a potential solution. That said, we won't be able to test and release a fix until Monday at the earliest. Because the outcome is not totally sure, I've deferred for now but will update when we know more.

Comment: The reason why your "exception" happens is because the question [was migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292823/questions-migrated-to-localized-meta-sites-get-the-discussion-tag-in-english-e). The part that adds the discussion tag to questions migrated to site metas doesn't check for (localized) synonyms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a crazy one! In short, there was a race condition. Reveal the spoiler for a more detailed explanation, as it contains the trigger for the hat:

> There was a race condition in the variable that stored the synonym for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tags across website, and they were all defaulting to "discussion" as opposed to the localized version (big thanks to [Roberta Arcoverde](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/253117/rla4) for figuring this one out!).

The race condition has been fixed. Going forward folks should now be able to attain the hat by performing the trigger. It is not possible to award hats going backwards to people that already did it though, since the actual detector wasn't being rendered to the page (sorry about that :( )

Comment: Thank you, Felippe and Roberta, for taking a look into this one :-). I can confirm it's working as expected now.