# Meta posts without required tags on some localized sites

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, localization, required-tags

I found that on some localized sites there are the posts without required tags:

[ruSO.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bdiscussion%5D%20-%5Bbug%5D%20-%5Bsupport%5D%20-%5Bfeature-request%5D)

> [image: ruso]

[esSO.meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bdiscussion%5D%20-%5Bbug%5D%20-%5Bsupport%5D%20-%5Bfeature-request%5D)

> [image: esso]

[rusSE.meta](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bdiscussion%5D%20-%5Bbug%5D%20-%5Bsupport%5D%20-%5Bfeature-request%5D)

> [image: russe]

It may be related to the old (but still persist) bug: [Questions migrated to localized meta sites get the [discussion] tag in English even if it's synonymized to the localized tag equivalent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292823/339911)

However [`stackoverflow`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow/synonyms) tag on ruSO.meta is not a synonym for [discussion] tag.

Comment: The timelines all show those are migrated questions, yes. Does that make this question a duplicate?

Comment: @Glorfindel not sure. Updated.

Comment: Perhaps because those questions were already tagged [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow) - but I agree, [discussion] should have been added. It reminds me of [Wrong tag order for migrated Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340503/4751173).